Pandas saved file not found in databricks CWD
I am saving a pandas dataframe as csv file from my databricks notebook using the command -
df.to_csv(cwd + '/data.csv', index=False)
This completes without any error. However, where can find this path in the GUI of databricks (how can I navigate to cwd basically)? In fact, when I try reading the same file again -
pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '/data.csv'),
it gives a file not found error [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Is there something wrong I am doing?
Another question on the similar lines I had was, how can I navigate to the CWD from the Databricks GUI?

In your example, cwd is a variable and not necessarily the result of os.getcwd(). Can you confirm the value of cwd? Maybe construct the entire path and then print / log it?

I assigned cwd to os.getcwd()

If you're just using the Databricks notebook, there's no way to access the saved CSV file through the GUI, to download or save it.
Here I've created a similar process you talked about, and you can see the file contents, and how to load that CSV file again using os.getcwd()

Here I'm adding a link, as I think, you need to just download the CSV file https://blog.det.life/4-proven-methods-to-download-files-from-databricks-locally-88d0352b4f85
If Uploaded data to DBFS (The causation most probably) :
The issue arises because, in Databricks, the os.getcwd() function returns a path related to the driver node's local file system, which is different from the distributed file system (DBFS) used by Databricks. This discrepancy leads to confusion as the file saved using os.getcwd() may not be in the expected location, especially when trying to read it back using the same method.
Saving the File: When you save the file using df.to_csv(cwd + '/data.csv', index=False), it is saved to a local path on the driver node's file system, not DBFS.
Reading the File: When you attempt to read the file using pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '/data.csv'), it looks for the file in the current working directory of the driver node, which might not be the same path where the file was saved.

I am getting the same error as before when using the above commands you said - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/tmp/data.csv'

It would help to print the variable cwd to help debug the issue.
I've tried recreating your scenario using the following code and was able to read the CSV without issues:
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframe
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Anna', 'Peter', 'Linda'],
        'Age': [28, 35, 42, 50],
        'Country': ['USA', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Australia']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(cwd + '/data.csv', index=False) 

In my case, cwd = /databricks/driver
You could also print all the files/directories in cwd using os.listdir(cwd) to see your file
Refer image here

you can improve the answer by elaborating, on how you wrote the data, then a ss of the os.listdir(cwd) to point the file, and then how you've managed to read the exact file, providing exact codes.
